# RedisGraph - UNWIND batch of queries

Tags: neo4j, redis, cypher, redis-py, redisgraph

I would like to execute a batch of queries in RedisGraph with the Python API in order to speed up the creation of big knowledge graphs.

In **Neo4J**, the *UNWIND* command can be used by the Neo4J Python API and allows to parallelize queries. In this snippet, you can seen how the Python API supports *UNWIND* - the `run` method takes `batch` as parameter. `batch` is a list of dictionaries. Every dictionary has `head_id`, `tail_id` and `properties` as keys.

```
with session.begin_transaction() as tx:  # In this transaction relationships are inserted in the database
    cypher_query = 'UNWIND $batch as row ' \
    'MATCH (head:Node) WHERE head.id = row.head_id ' \
    'MATCH (tail:Node) WHERE tail.id = row.tail_id ' \
    'CREATE (head)-[rel:RELATIONSHIP]->(tail) ' \
    'SET rel += row.properties'

     tx.run(cypher_query, batch=batch)
```

In **RedisGraph**, *UNWIND* is also available (as it is a Cypher command). However, I don't know how to pass a batch in the Python API:

```
cypher_query = 'UNWIND $batch as row ' \
        'MATCH (head:Node) WHERE head.id = row.head_id ' \
        'MATCH (tail:Node) WHERE tail.id = row.tail_id ' \
        'CREATE (head)-[rel:RELATIONSHIP]->(tail) ' \
        'SET rel += row.properties'
r = redis.StrictRedis()
r.execute_command('GRAPH.QUERY', graph_name, cypher_query)  #No batch can be passed!!
```

Do you know a solution? Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/RedisGraph/RedisGraph/issues/1293

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the answer from the RedisLabs dev team:

github.com/RedisGraph/RedisGraph/issues/1293

As of now, the feature is not supported, but will be introduced in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The `redisgraph-py` README shows an [example](https://github.com/RedisGraph/redisgraph-py#example-using-the-python-client) of how to pass parameters via its `query()` method:

> ```
> ...
> params = {'purpose':"pleasure"}
> query = """MATCH (p:person)-[v:visited {purpose:$purpose}]->(c:country)
>      RETURN p.name, p.age, v.purpose, c.name"""
>
> result = redis_graph.query(query, params)
> ...
> ```

If you really need to use `execute_command()` instead, you can take a look at [how `query()` is implemented](https://github.com/RedisGraph/redisgraph-py/blob/387e86dc734c05fb1b93a54740987a5ab7ae3ea0/redisgraph/graph.py#L120).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think redis_graph.query(query, params) does not really implement what I was looking for. In the snipped I posted in my question, batch is a list of dictionaries, which is then unwinded by the UNWIND command. query() does not seem to support that.